# find Number of ways to get total of 17cents (for example) using 1,5,10,25,50 cents

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic, dynamic-programming, recurrence

Why do i get a stack overflow error the thing is im trying to solve this recursively as a start,before i start using dynamic programming .In the method coins,"a" is the array that holds the coins that will form the total i want,sum is the total i want (17 for example),and i represents he index of the array that i am at

```
import java.util.*;
public class dp2 {//RECURSIVE WAY THEN OPTIMIZE TO DP
  public static int coins (int [] a, int sum,int i){

    if (sum==0)
        return 1;
    else if (i==a.length){
        return 0;
    }
    else if (i>a.length&&sum<a[i]){
        return coins(a,sum,i++);
    }

    else {
        return coins(a,sum-a[i],i++)+coins(a,sum-a[i],i);
    }
  }

  public static void main (String [] args ){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    while (sc.hasNext()){
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int y=x;
        int [] a ={1,5,10,25,50};
        int w = coins(a,y,0);
        System.out.println("There are " +w+ " ways to produce "+x + " coins change.");
    }               
  }

}
```

Comment: This is probably an infinite recursive call, check your condition ( your code, you should find the problem faster than us). Or could be a lot of recursive call but this is unlikely that you overload the stack. Use debugged to track the calls

Comment: This is an infinite recursive call.

Comment: One word of advice as a side note: you should stick to one way to format single-line statements (and I'd suggest always using curly braces) since mixing it might result in confusion and hard to spot bugs. What I mean is things like this your first if-block as opposed to the else-if-block that follows.

Comment: I cant figure out what is wrong with my conditions.i checked them several times

Comment: Try to debug it

Comment: you should we aware that `i++` returns the value of `i` **before** incrementing it. There is no reason to use `i++` in a statement like `return call(i++);` The passed value is not incremented, and the incremented value of `i` is never used since the method is terminated by the `return`.

Comment: I guess is almost impossible to find all possible ways to get the exact amount, imagine for a big amount like 500, you could have 500 times 1, or  495 times 1 plus 5 or 490 times 1 plus 2 times 5...this exercise usually is solved by the logic of find the exact amount with the less number of coins possible, but find all different possibilities is almost impossible

Comment: @cralfaro why is it almost impossible? it just takes some time (and some logic)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger thats why i said almost, is possible, but the complexitity will be high, you have 2 problems here 1. detect the exact amount with a badge of coins, 2. check the combination of coins is not a combination you already tried because need to be differents. Not impossible, but far to be trivial

Comment: @cralfaro - shit, then I must have done something wrong... my result `59576 alternatives for 500
in 47ms` and the recursive method is less than 20 lines (including method declaration and empty lines) but I have not really tested it in that short time

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger really looking to see that master piece :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133629/discussion-between-carlos-heuberger-and-cralfaro).

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with infinity loop.

First check, what do you want to return, because actually you can return only 1 or 0. So, where is other condition? Example: i == a.length - 1 or sum < 0 ? I think, you want to return sum.

And next, if you put example 17, so where is mechanism to choose witch coins from array you can select?

And next, please change `return coins(a,sum-a[i],++i)+coins(a,sum-a[i],i);`, because in your code **i** is always 0

So, maybe is good exaple code for You:

```
class dp2 {//RECURSIVE WAY THEN OPTIMIZE TO DP
  public static int coins (int [] a, int sum,int i){
    if (sum==0)
        return 1;
    else if (i==a.length){
        return 0;
    }else if(i + 1 == a.length || sum < 0 || sum - a[i] < 0){ //Your break condition ?
        return sum;
    }
    else if (i>a.length&&sum<a[i]){
        return coins(a,sum,i++);
    }

    else {
        return coins(a,sum-a[i],++i)+coins(a,sum-a[i],i);
    }
  }
  public static void main (String [] args ){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    while (sc.hasNext()){
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int y=x;
        int [] a ={1,5,10,25,50};
        int w = coins(a,y,0);
        System.out.println("There are " +w+ " ways to produce "+x + " coins change.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the thing is i dont want to keep track of which coins i will choose i just want to know the number of ways that i can combine these coins to form the sum i have so basically when i subtract (sum-a[i]) im decreasing the sum till it reaches zero once it reaches zero then i return one the two possible ways is either  i take the same coin more than once or go to the next coin : return coins(a,sum-a[i],i)+coins(a,sum-a[i],++i);

Comment: Ok, so is still same problem with increment, and with break conditions. So, I give two advices: 1) about increment, and 2) about break condition :)

Answer (score 0):

I added one statement to your code, at line 4:

```
System.out.println(sum + ", " + i);
```

Give the input 27, the output was:

```
27, 0
26, 0
25, 0
.... decreasing by one each time...
3, 0
2, 0
1, 0
0, 0
-4, 1
-9, 1
-14, 1
```

And then it never stops because you don't check for `sum < 0`.

You should be able to figure it out from there... `println`: the lightest-weight debugger in the world :-)

Comment: I have a line in my code;

         else if (i<a.length&&sum<a[i]){
   return coins(a,sum,++i);
  }
that is if a[i] is greater than sum i wont subtract hence i wont reach anything less than zero.why isnt this enough instead of sum <0

Comment: That's not a terminating condition, though - it just results in another call to `coins`. If a recursive function runs away and overflows the stack you need to check your terminating conditions, initially, and then fix whatever other problems you find along the way.

Comment: For terminating i have two conditions when sum reaches zero and i<a.length and if sum!=0 and i reaches a.length again why arent these sufficient ?

Comment: You will learn more by figuring this out for yourself than if I just tell you. Add more `println`s to the code, one in each of the four branches, so that you know where the code is going. Maybe add another parameter just to track the call depth. Note that, in my sample output, the value of `sum` did hit zero, so at least one invocation of `coins` returned 1 at that point. What happened next?